# SQL Trigger to Insert a row in Table B is the record is inserted in Table A

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update, insert

I have a requirement where I have to Insert a Record into Table "Site" after the record is inserted into InventOperationalSiteStaging Table. I created a SQL trigger which is **working fine for single record** scenario but **failing when I insert multiple records at a time**. Here is the trigger code. Please gjuide me to fix this issue.

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[InventSiteAfterInsert] on [dbo].[InventOperationalSiteStaging]
After Insert,Update 
AS


DECLARE @SiteId varchar (10),
       @SiteName varchar(60),
       @Description VARCHAR(200),
       @DeleteIndicator bit,
       @ExternalKey VARCHAR(400); 

SELECT @SiteId = ins.SITEID FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @SiteName = ins.SITENAME FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @ExternalKey = ins.MV2ExternalKey FROM INSERTED ins;
;
set @DeleteIndicator = 0;


MERGE Site AS [target] 
USING (SELECT [i].MV2ExternalKey FROM INSERTED AS [i]) AS source
ON ([target].Name = [source].MV2ExternalKey)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE  SET 
         Name = @SiteID,
         Description = @SiteName,
         DeleteIndicator = @DeleteIndicator
    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
       [Name]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ExternalKey]
      ,[DeleteIndicator]) 
VALUES (@SiteId,
    @SiteName,
    @ExternalKey,
    @DeleteIndicator );
```

Comment: Failing you say: What error are you getting? Or is it doing the wrong thing? Please edit your question rather than replying here.

Comment: See also [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use your "source"  as supplier for it.
Because you are using variables , which holds only one value , this is way is working fine with one statement.

`MERGE` and `trigger` statements can work with multiple rows at once, not just one , so just use the special `INSERTED` table inside the `MERGE` statement; just replace the your `MERGE` statement with next `MERGE` statement, inside your `trigger` code

Here are some samples : [example1](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-merge-statement-overview-and-examples/) ,
[example2](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/)

```
MERGE Site AS [target] 
USING (SELECT [i].MV2ExternalKey,i.SiteID,i.siteName,@DeleteIndicator as DeleteIndicator FROM INSERTED AS [i]) AS source
ON ([target].Name = [source].MV2ExternalKey)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE  SET 
         Name = source.SITEID,
         Description = source.SITENAME,
         DeleteIndicator = source.DeleteIndicator
    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
       [Name]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ExternalKey]
      ,[DeleteIndicator]) 
VALUES( source.siteID,source.siteName,source.MV2ExternalKey,source.DeleteIndicator)
```

so , the trigger code will become:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[InventSiteAfterInsert] on [dbo].[InventOperationalSiteStaging]
After Insert,Update 
AS


MERGE Site AS [target] 
    USING (SELECT [i].MV2ExternalKey,i.SiteID,i.siteName, 0 as DeleteIndicator FROM INSERTED AS [i]) AS source
    ON ([target].Name = [source].MV2ExternalKey)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE  SET 
             Name = source.SITEID,
             Description = source.SITENAME,
             DeleteIndicator = source.DeleteIndicator
        
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Name],[Description],[ExternalKey],[DeleteIndicator]) 
    VALUES( source.siteID, source.siteName, source.MV2ExternalKey, source.DeleteIndicator);
```

As @Charlieface mentioned in comment section, in case of an update with the same values, some people, will not perform update.

```
USING (SELECT [i].MV2ExternalKey,i.SiteID,i.siteName, 0 as DeleteIndicator FROM INSERTED AS [i]) AS source
```

will become

```
USING (SELECT [i].MV2ExternalKey,i.SiteID,i.siteName, 0 as DeleteIndicator FROM INSERTED AS [i] 
EXCEPT 
SELECT d.MV2ExternalKey,d.SiteID,d.siteName, 0 as DeleteIndicator FROM DELETED AS d) AS source
```

ps: there are some bugs on merge statement, so be careful
[link1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), [link2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug)